# Android- How to reverse the position of text in checkbox

Tags: android, android-layout, android-widget

Is there any attribute to change the text position in checkbox view without creating a separate text view?

It must be like

Text -------> checkbox

Answer (score 2):

It worked for me like this, with layoutDirection:

```
<CheckBox
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="I'm left of the box!!!"
    android:layoutDirection="rtl"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's how

```
    <CheckBox 
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:button="@null"
            android:drawableRight="@drawable/checkbox_selector"
            android:text="The Label goes here"
        />
```

The trick is that you have to define a selector drawable, specify the bitmaps of all 4 states, then use that selector as the drawableRight.

This way you can specify the checkbox in all 4 sides of the label (left right top and bottom)